# Add tag synonym for report

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Can someone add [reports](/questions/tagged/reports) as synonym for [report](/questions/tagged/report)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed: [reports](/questions/tagged/reports) --> [report](/questions/tagged/report)